# Playing with SP Database, will it break SP directly?

Tags: database, schema

I am ready about SharePoint databases and what could happen if someone messes with them, all I've seen is that they can affect the upgrade of SharePoint because messing with them could change the schema and the schema is important at upgrade time, but will it break the farm once the user changes the database manually or it will break at upgrade time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will be out of support of Microsoft.
2. I dont think we can predict what will goes wrong as its depend what you change/ add/delete?

Microsoft cannot reliably predict the effect to the operation of these products when parties other than the Microsoft SharePoint Development Team or Microsoft SharePoint Support agents make changes to the database schema, modify its data, or execute ad hoc queries against the SharePoint databases.

Examples of unsupported database changes include, but are not limited to, the following:

- Adding database triggers
- Adding new indexes or changing existing indexes within tables
- Adding, changing, or deleting any primary or foreign key relationships
- Changing or deleting existing stored procedures
- Calling existing stored procedures directly, except as described in the SharePoint Protocols documentation
- Adding new stored procedures
- Adding, changing, or deleting any data in any table of any of the databases for the products that are listed in the "Applies to" section
- Adding, changing, or deleting any columns in any table of any of the databases for the products that are listed in the "Applies to" section
- Making any modification to the database schema
- Adding tables to any of the databases for the products that are listed in the "Applies to" section
- Changing the database collation
- Running DBCC_CHECKDB WITH REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS (However, running DBCC_CHECKDB WITH REPAIR_FAST and REPAIR_REBUILD is supported, as these commands only update the indexes of the associated database.)
- Enabling SQL Server change data capture (CDC)
- Enabling SQL Server transactional replication
- Enabling SQL Server merge replication

If an unsupported database modification is discovered during a support call, the customer must perform one of the following procedures at a minimum:

Perform a database restoration from the last known good backup that did not include the database modifications

Roll back all the database modifications

**References**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841057

[Five reasons not to directly query SharePoint databases](http://www.sharepoint4arabs.com/AymanElHattab/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=99)